# How to show confirmation message in jQuery on button click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing web application in asp.net. My requirement is to show confirmation message on every button click event like (Insert, update and delete buttons). I am using jQuery message box in through out the application for successfull insert,update and delete.

```
    function MessageBox(Title, InnerText) {
    try {
        var dialog = $('<p class="messagebox">' + InnerText + '</p>').dialog({
            title: Title,
            width: "240",
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {
                    dialog.dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        MessageBox('Tracker Alert', e);
    }
}
```

Call on button click event

```
Result = Save_UpdateData(2);
 if (Result > 0)
   {             
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "msg", "MessageBox('Tracker Alert', 'Record updated succesfully');", true);
     }
```

Then, how to show confirmation message on button click event by using jQuery message box like same as above function?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).on('mouseover', (function () {
          window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
      }));
      $(window).on('mouseout', (function () {
          window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
      }));
      function ConfirmLeave() {         
          return "";
      }
 var prevKey = "";
  $(document).keydown(function (e) {
      if (e.key == "F5") {
          window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
      }
      else if (e.key.toUpperCase() == "W" && prevKey == "CONTROL") {
          window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
      }
      else if (e.key.toUpperCase() == "R" && prevKey == "CONTROL") {
          window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
      }
      else if (e.key.toUpperCase() == "F4" && (prevKey == "ALT" || prevKey == "CONTROL")) {
          window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
      }
      prevKey = e.key.toUpperCase();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I want confirmation message  like ("Are you sure, you want to update this record") click on  "ok" button then call "Save_UpdateData(2)" function  and click on "cancel" then close dialog box.